# Javascript kinetics: rect resize

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have following codes for a Rect by kinetics, why I could not resize the rect though I have resize properties defined in the rect.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 578,
    height: 200
  });

  var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

  var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
    x: 239,
    y: 75,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: 'green',
    stroke: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 4,
    resize: true
  });

  // add the shape to the layer
  layer.add(rect);

  // add the layer to the stage
  stage.add(layer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS has no `resize` property.

You have to resize manually:

```
rect.setSize(newWidth,newHeight);
layer.draw();
```

Comment: How could I see all properties related to layer? Are there kinectics api documents?

Comment: How let rect receive onclick event?

Comment: Here are some good tutorials on KineticJS: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/ and here is the documention (warning: the docs seem to be auto-generated, resulting in some classes **saying** they allow certain properties/methods but they really don’t)

Comment: You can have a rect listen for click events like this: myRect.on("click", function(){...respond as you like...});